# Meteor database design for hierarchical structure

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, nosql

I'm new to Meteor and Mongo, and I have some basic database design questions.

Let's say I'm making a turn based strategy game like [Advance Wars](http://gamingmemoirs.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Advance-Wars-Screenshot.jpg?w=600).  I'm not sure how to structure my data.

I made a little demo where I did this in my html:

```
{{#each chars}}
  <div class='char' style={{get_style}}>
      ...
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

And I have this helper defined on Template.body:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  chars: function() {
    return Characters.find({});
  },
  ...
})
```

This works fine when I only have one game running at a time.  But I'm not sure how to make this work when I have multiple games running concurrently.

I guess one way to do it would be to have a Games collection.  Each of these Games references two or more Players and each Player could have a list of Characters.  Each Character could have an x and y position.  But then I'm not sure what query I would replace `Characters.find({})` with.

I guess it could be something like `Game.findOne({game_id: game_id}).players[player_id].characters`.  But I'm not sure what the performance implications are there.  Would Meteor pull down the entire game object every time a character moves?  I don't really understand what Meteor is doing under the hood.

I guess another possibility that would require minimal changes would be to do something like `Characters.find({game_id: 123, player_id: 1})`.  And then I would have all the Characters from all the games in one big collection.  It seems a bit strange to me to not have the Characters "encapsulated" under a Game, but maybe this is the way to go.

Actually, now that I've written that out, it seems like the second option makes more sense.  And I guess I would define all other internal game objects as separate collections.  Is this a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's pretend your collection stores items that look like

```
{
  _id: String,
  started: Date,
  players: [{
    _id: String,
    name: String,
    characters: [{
      _id: String,
      x: Number,
      y: Number
    }, {
      // ...
    }]
  }, {
    // ...
  }]
}
```

If you have an `_id` of a game and you need to get all the players and their characters, you do simply

```
let gameId = 'whatever';
const games = Games.find({
  _id: gameId
});
```

After that, in `games`, you have a cursor that will allow you to iterate over a single element, a game you selected by its ID (which is unique by design).

Then, in your template, you do

```
<div class="games">
  {{#each games}}
    <h1>{{started}} — game's `started` scalar property.</h1>
    {{#each players}}
      <div class="player" id="{{_id}}">
        <h2 id="{{_id}}">{{name}} — player's name</h2>
        {{#each characters}}
          <h3 id="{{_id}}">{{x}}, {{y}} — coordinates of a character</h3>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Note how `_id` respects current context.

Another way to do the same is use a plain-object instead of cursor, but your should use it only in cases you guarantee the query result to be a single element:

```
let gameId = 'whatever';
const game = Games.findOne({
  _id: gameId
});
```

The template will look a bit different. Since you have a single plain-object, you don't have anything to iterate over. So you can access properties of this object omitting the topmost context and replacing it with a `with` block:

```
<div class="game">
  {{#with game}}
    <h1>{{started}} — game's `started` scalar property.</h1>
    {{#each players}}
      <div class="player" id="{{_id}}">
        <h2 id="{{_id}}">{{name}} — player's name</h2>
        {{#each characters}}
          <h3 id="{{_id}}">{{x}}, {{y}} — coordinates of a character</h3>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  {{/with}}
</div>
```

Please make sure that your template (or either the whole client) is subscribed to the `Games` collection, and this collection is published on the server and returns the whole field set and doesn't query the data (or it does but you control it).